# Help with android augmented reality 

Tags: android, augmented-reality, object-recognition

i just need some guide on how to detect a marker and make an output text.. for ex: a marker with an image of a dog , when detected, i have an output text "DOG" in a textfield .. can someone help me with my idea? oh, btw which one is more effective to use nyartoolkit or andar for my idea?thanks:) need help..!

Comment: see this fruitful thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039334/communication-between-two-apps-using-emulator-as-server-and-client

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for isn't augmented reality, it's object recognition.  AR is chiefly concerned with presenting data overlaid on the the real world, so computation is devoted each frame to determining the position relative to the camera of the object.  If you don't intent to use this data, AR libraries may be an inefficient.  That said...

AR marker tracking libraries usually find markers by prominent features like corners, and can distinguish markers by binary patters encoded inside the marker, or in the marker's borders.  If you're happy with having the "dog" part encoded in the border of a marker, there are libraries you can use like [Qualcomm's AR development kit](http://developer.qualcomm.com/ar).  This library, and [Metaio's Unifeye mobile](http://www.metaio.com/products/mobile/) can also do natural feature tracking on pre-defined images.  If you're happy with being able to recognize one specific image or images of dogs that you have defined in advance, either of these should be ok.  You might have to manipulate your dog images to get good features they can identify and track.  Natural objects can be problematic.

General object recognition (being able to recognize a picture of any dog, not known beforehand) is still a research topic. There are approaches, but they're mostly very computationally intensive, and most mobile solutions involve offloading the serious computation to a server.  Recognition of simple outline sketches however is more tractable, there's a great paper called "Shape recognition and pose estimation for mobile augmented reality" (I can't find a copy online, but the [IEEE link is here](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/ISMAR.2009.5336498)) that uses contours to identify objects - this is light enough to run on a mobile (and it's pure genius).