# Communication between two apps using emulator as server and client

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

I have a problem. I want to make an `emulator` on my computer as a server. Then I want to communicate to another application installed on another emulator on the same computer.Or this may be two phone also.similarly two emulator communicate as server client

I searched on Google but I found no relevant answers.

**Problem:**

1)I have two emulators or phone`

2)I want one work as server and the other to work as a client, and I want to 
    communicate between them

Comment: You should be much more detailed about what you want and what you already tried. Your current question is not really answerable.

Comment: @WarrenFaith he wants to emulate "two devices in the same local network" on two instances of android emulator running on the same PC, i think

Comment: @Selvin ,yes you are right.What is right way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solve my problem using socket programming with [help of this Blog](http://www.happygeek.in/socket-programming-in-android).I use server and client code and then use ADB to start one emulator as server.Thank you all for your help and support

Comment: @menukadevinda Yes , Jesus owner has sold his website :D. Let me find some other links i will change it

Comment: @Trickster Actual link has been deleted by Post anther. I am trying to find out any related link but still not succeeded. Because of this i got many down vote :).

Answer (score 5):

For 2 apps on the same virtual (or real) device to work together, besides the regular Intent object, you might have a look at bound Services and AIDL : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: Yes its seems interesting, i will go through it completely  and need to see that it will solve my problem or not

Comment: it will not help you ... he didn't understand your question

Comment: that's right i didn't correctly understand the question in its first phrasing, don't look into my reply as a solution to client-server architecture on 2 different devices ; besides, don't assume everyone here is male since "he" is a "she" :)

Comment: Why so many upvotes... this does not answer the question at all?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this step if you connect your emulator with socket:

1. run the first emulator as server
2. telnet localhot 5554 from terminal
3. redir add tcp:5000:6000
4. run the second emulator as client
5. input the ip from server and port

NB : tcp:5000:6000 is the port from server and client, 5000 is from client and 6000 as server port.

Comment: Up vote for all, you all guys made this community worth it.I love to here.Actually right now i am doing other work but  i will go for every answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want network connection between the two, you can do it, but each emulator is running behind its own virtual router. The 'Using The Emulator' documentation will help:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#connecting

Comment: yes its nice but have to see that it will help or not.One upvote for your responce